# Send Apache Catalina Logs to Logstash

Tags: linux, centos, tcp, udp, elasticsearch

Dependencies :

**OS Version : CentOS 5.0**

**Server Environment : Production**

**Logstash Version : 5.0**

**Elasticsearch Version : 5.0**

I have several app servers running on CentOS 5.0. All these are on-premise  production servers. I have ELK stack setup on AWS. All these app servers generating Apache Catalina Logs and I want to send all these logs to logstash server for parsing.

Problem: 
I was planning to use filebeat 5.0 to send all those logs to logstash but all those app servers running on CentOS 5.0 and filebeat does not support centos 5.0.I checked on ELK community and I found this [answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-and-centos-5/43308).

Is there any way to send all these logs to logstash like from TCP / UDP sockets? If yes, how I can do that? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure an input in Logstash with something like:

```
input {
      tcp {
          port => 5000
          type => syslog
      }
}
```